# MATLAB reading a mixed data type binary file

Tags: matlab, types, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am having trouble reading a very large binary file (1,000,000 bytes +)

If I `fread` the file in a 1 byte data format for example `'uint8'` the number of data read equals the size of the file so memory isn't an issue.

I know in this binary file there is data of type `'int16'` and `'single'` however I don't know the structure of the file. I think the file is structured so there is an `'int16'` data point followed by a `'single'` data point and this is repeated until the end of the file.

I do not know how to do this reading of mixed data types.

I think I need a loop of some sort?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions given

Comment: I suggest you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010039/create-a-2-column-matrix-with-2-different-format-types/32015030#32015030) and you use the solution #1 (=read everything in `uint8` then use [`typecast`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) to get your `int16` ans `single`). Note that the other solutions will work too, the first one is just the fastest and recommended one.

Answer (score 0):

using the skip property allows to read the `single` and  `uint16` in one step each

```
A = fread(fileID,sizeA,precision,skip)
```

Not tested Sample Code:

```
Integer16 = fread(fileID,sizeA,'uint16',8); %read uin16 and skip the siz eof a single
fseek(fileID, 2, 0) % offset the size of a uint16 
Single = fread(fileID,sizeA,'single',2); % read the singles
```

Comment: brrrr!! ... I know Matlab is case sensitive so `single` and `Single` are different symbols, but in practice I would seriously refrain to name any variable `Single` (or any case variation of it). That's a recipe for disaster...