# MATLAB writing a mixed data type via UDP

Tags: matlab, binary, udp, send

Similar to [MATLAB reading a mixed data type binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457759/matlab-reading-a-mixed-data-type-binary-file)
I want to send a binary UDP telegram of mixed datatypes to a third party device.

The third party device expects a data block consisting of 1024 bytes. This block contains `int16`, `uint32` and `single` values. To send the data I assumed I have to use the `fwrite` function (Instrument Control Toolbox).

My question is:
How can i wrap several data types (int16, uint32 etc.) into one binary variable to send it via `fwrite`? Any help is appreciated!